# IIS Request Count/ IIS Stop Gracefully

Tags: iis-8

Please help me to get number of IIS request currently being processed or that are in the request queue.

Basically I am trying to stop IIS gracefully, without impacting existing users/requests.

Comment: With out impacting to existing requests

Comment: Launch Performance Monitor and read the IIS counters. It would be the responsibility of developers to write the web apps in a fault tolerant way. Generally speaking, you cannot stop IIS gracefully, and crashes are quite common.